# Confusing Google Admin console options related to Google Drive's sharing security update

Tags: google-drive

I'm reviewing the notification from Google today that starts:

> On September 13, 2021, Drive will apply a security update to make file sharing more secure. As a Google Workspace admin, you can choose how this update is applied in your domain.

In our admin console, I find this section:
[image]

The helptext on this page says "If you apply the security update before July 23, users will be notified of their impacted files".

What confuses me is, exactly how am I supposed to "apply the security update before July 23"? These are the default options that have been selected for me. The Save button is disabled.

It seems my only option is to do nothing (which is likely) then have users notified on July 26. Am I missing something?

Other references:

This article describes it fairly succinctly:
https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/06/23/a-google-drive-update-is-going-to-break-a-bunch-of-your-links/

From the Google Workspace blog:
https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/06/drive-file-link-updates.html

Answer (score 0):

It’s odd that the save option is disabled. What I read from google is that admins should be able to control how this update is rolled out. Since the update is to make Drive more secure, some sharing links are going to be broken. Not a bad idea to make end users aware of that.